# How can I have a String attached to an array of ints?

Tags: java, arrays, int

I've done some research on this site about this already, however, I'm having some trouble finding something I can use. I'm trying to create a similar program to pokemon, but much much simpler and text based. Currently I'm using arrays to store the Pokemon's stats. That's working great, but when I need to print the Pokemon's name I have to manually type it out. This has worked fine, but I want to have the player battle a random Pokemon. This is my current code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Declare the Pokemon to be used
    int[] Player    = {0,  0,  0,   0,  0,   0  };
    int[] Blastoise = {79, 83, 100, 85, 105, 78 };
    int[] Raichu    = {60, 90, 55,  90, 80,  110};
    int[][] Pokemon = new int[][] {Blastoise, Raichu, Player};

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    startBattle(input, Pokemon)
}
public static String startBattle(Scanner input, int[][] Pokemon) {
        System.out.println("A wild Pokemon appeared!");
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * 1);
        System.out.println("A wild " + **POKEMON NAME** + " appeared!");
        System.out.print("What Pokemon do you choose? ");
        String userPokemon = input.next();
        return userPokemon;
    }
```

Where it says POKEMON NAME is where I want to have the Pokemon's name be. I know it's super difficult to get the name of an array, or add a String to an int array (I would add the name to the list[0] spot). Is there any way I could at least associate a String with one of the lists so I could call the name of that randomly selected Pokemon? Thanks!

Comment: Look into the object oriented aspect of Java and use each pokemon as if they were their own object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a class.  Give it properties that represent things that describe your real-world entity, in this case a Pokemon.

The properties at a minimum are a string representing the name and the integer array you use to describe a character.

Here's an example:

```
public class Pokemon {
    private String name;

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    private int hp;

    public int getHP() { return this.hp; }
    public void setHP(int hp) { this.hp = hp; }

    // Repeat the pattern for all properties that describe a Pokemon
    // hp, attack, defense, special attack, special defense, and speed
}
```

Comment: dealing with stats in an array can get very tedious if you don't have them as named properties.  `"wait, what was  ATK? the third number or fourth?"` so i would definitely recommend this approach

Comment: That's a good point.  I'm not sure what the numbers represent, but if they are status values it is a good idea to add separate properties to the class instead of using an integer array.

Comment: you should give them a code example :)  i think that would help.

Comment: @EricJ. just name the fields like "HP", "Attack", "Defence" if you plan to give an example.

Comment: The numbers are the stats, in order: hp, attack, defense, special attack, special defense, and speed. What should the class I create contain?